# Confusion on multivariable partial differentiation from textbook

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am very confused about a use of the partial differential multivariable chain rule. The textbook first describes the formula:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}$

But then, as shown in the image provided, they set $s = x$ and call x to be a function of x, y to be a function of y, z to be a function of x and y, and make:

$f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$.

But then on one side they claim:

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ *

And on the other side they have:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = (2x)(0) + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})(0) + (2z)(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})$ (1)

So then $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$, but this is in direct contradiction with (*) above. This leads to large issues in equation (1), since the $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ should cancel from both sides, but it does not for some reason.

Can someone please explain what is going on?

[textbook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJh3N.png)

Comment: They're doing this implicitly.

Comment: Note that the book says $z=z(x,y)$.

Comment: What you have written in your question is not what it says in the textbook.  Perhaps if you compare them carefully, things will be plainer to you.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, I will try to understand the issues in my interpretation. However, my main question is why ∂f/∂x achieves different values on LHS and RHS.

Comment: It doesn't.  There are two different methods of computing it, and of course, they have to be equal.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear with the above statement, I meant to say that: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = f_x$ is the definition in the textbook, so if LHS = RHS, then: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (f_x)(1) + (f_y)(0) + (f_z)(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})$ leads to: $0 = (f_y)(0) + (f_z)(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})$, which seems very incorrect.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you mean.  Good question.  I'll try to compose an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's very bad notation to use $\partial f/\partial x$ and $f_x$ for two different things, as they do. And in general it often leads to confusion when one uses the same name for the *quantity* that depends on some other quantities as for the *function* which describes this dependence.

If you want to clean it up, write $z=Z(y,z)$ instead of $z=z(x,y)$ (so that the function's name is $Z$, different from the variable name $z$), and write
$$
F(x,y) = f(x,y,Z(x,y)) = x^2 + y^2 + Z(x,y)^2
$$
for the composite function, which is actually the constant function $F(x,y)=4$ since that's how $Z(x,y)$ is defined. This function $F$ is a function of two variables, so it's clearly not the same as the three-variable function $f$, so it should have a different name.

Then what they denote by $\partial f/\partial x$ is really $\partial F/\partial x$, and it's zero on the one hand (since $F$ is constant), and given by the chain rule on the other hand (since $F$ is a composite function):
$$
\begin{split}
0 = F_x(x,y)
& = f_x(x,y,Z(x,y)) + f_z(x,y,Z(x,y)) \, Z_x(x,y)
\\
& = 2x + 2 Z(x,y) \, Z_x(x,y)
.
\end{split}
$$
This shows that
$$
Z_x(x,y)
= - \frac{f_x(x,y,Z(x,y))}{f_z(x,y,Z(x,y))}
= - \frac{x}{Z(x,y)}
.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$x^2+y^2+z^2=4.\tag{1}$$ As the book says, we can view this equation as defining $z$ as a function of the independent variables $x$ and $y$.  Obviously, there is more than one possible function $z.$  Now if we consider the explicit function $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$ where $z$ is the implicit function we just discussed, then we have$${\partial f\over \partial x} = 2x\cdot1+2y\cdot0+2z\cdot{\partial z\over\partial x}\tag{2}$$ This is true regardless of $(1)$.

As I understand your question, you are asking, "If we know from $(1)$ that $f_x=0$ why don't we have $0$ instead of $2x$ on the right-hand side of $(2)?$"  The short answer is that it would be premature.  Equation $(2)$ expresses a general rule, which is true whenever $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.  It has nothing to do with an implicitly defined function.  You could substitute $z=\sin(xy)$ and $(2)$ would be true.

Now, we know from $(1)$ that with this particular value of $z,$ we have $f_x=0,$ so we can substitute this on the left-hand side of $(2)$ and solve for ${\partial z\over\partial x}.$

I'm sure there's a better way to express what I'm trying to say, but I hope this will make things a bit clearer to you.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the fundamental confusion, which I think is the following: if $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then obviously $\partial f/\partial x=2x$, so how come $\partial f/\partial x=0$ all of a sudden? As I've tried to explain in my answer, this is because the same letter $f$ (confusingly) is used to denote two different functions.

Comment: It may be obvious, but it isn't true.  If $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ then equation $(2)$ holds.  If $z$ happens to be such that equation $(1)$ holds, then $f_x=0.$  Your formula is correct if $x,y,$ and $z$ are independent variables, but they aren't.

Comment: My point is that the source of the confusion is this kind of notation, where you have to read from the context what depends on what. In the equation $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ one is defining a three-variable function $f(x,y,z)$, and looking at a level set of that function. But the symbol $f$ still denotes a three-variable function, whose partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x$ or $f_x$ or however you denote it **is** indisputably equal to $2x$. In the image in the question, they have indeed written $f_x$ in one place and in the next line written that it equals $2x$. (cont.)

Comment: But in the same place they start out $0 = \partial f/\partial x = \dots$, where the **same** symbol $f$ now stands for **another** function. And **that** function's partial with respect to $x$ is zero. So it's no wonder (to me) that students get confused.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, I agree that it would be better if they used different letters, but this kind of thing is ubiquitous in calculus.  In the chain rule $${dy\over dx}={dy\over du}{du\over dx},$$ $y$ means different things on the two sides of the equation.